# File save method

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, c#-3.0

How do I code a File Save Method To write data from the collection to the file specified in the File Name.
I'm not sure on how to go about coding this Code.
 Examples would be appreciated.

My code won't work it just comes up with syntax errors.

```
 public save
    {
      File.WriteAllLines(TransactionList, TransactionCollection.Select(item =>  item.ToString()));

    }
```

Comment: maybe have a look at System.IO.File http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.aspx

Comment: Need more information - what's in the collection?  How do you want it formatted?

Comment: The first argument needs to be a path to the file you want to write to (or create). And you code snippet is not legal c#.

Comment: If you don't even know how to write a method, then you shouldn't be trying to write a method that _does_ anything.

Answer (score 2):

It depends completely on how you want to save the data.

For example, if you want to save one item per line, you can use [File.WriteAllLines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383693.aspx):

```
File.WriteAllLines(theFilename, theCollection.Select(item => item.ToString()));
```

However, there are many, many other options.  The [System.IO Namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/29kt2zfk.aspx) provides all of the required functionality to read and write to files.

Comment: SO that's how I would do it in my Collection class?

Comment: @Ben This will write every item of a collection to a file, one line each, using the item's `ToString()` method to convert the item into text.  Without knowing what's in the collection, or how you want the output formatted, there's no way to provide better details.

Comment: Do I need to create a instance of my collection?

Comment: @Ben Yes, of course.  The whole point would be to save the items within the collection you already have...

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways. I suggest you start playing with these two classes:

- [StreamWriter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamwriter.aspx)
- [FileStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filestream.aspx)

Use the FileStream to create/open a file, and the StreamWriter to actually write the file. There are code examples in the documentation.

Should you need to read a file, there is also the corresponding [StremReader class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of writing text to a file: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6ka1wd3w.aspx
Here's an example of using the `FileOpenDialog` to get the user to select a file: http://www.dotnetperls.com/openfiledialog

If you need more specific information you'll need to add more information / ask a new question.

Answer (score 0):

Seeing that you seem to need an example to compare to your code you can try this. It's just a collection of fields and it's added to a list of comma separated strings if you don't need the commas just replace the comma with a space or tab or whatever.

GL.

```
void Main()
{
    var fields = new List<Field>{
        new Field{Id = 1, Name = "A"},
        new Field{Id = 2, Name = "B"},
        new Field{Id = 3, Name = "C"},
    };

    // Makes a list of strings with comma separated fields         
    var list_Of_CSV_Items = fields.Select(x => string.Join(",", x.Id,x.Name));

    System.IO.File.WriteAllLines(@"C:\WriteCommaSeparatedLines.txt", list_Of_CSV_Items);

}

public class Field
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public string Name {get; set;}
}
```